# onLoadChildren must call detach(), MusicBrowserService, Android?

Tags: android, audio-player, mediabrowserservicecompat, mediabrowserservice, android-music-player

I am using MediaBrowserService to play audio on the device.
When I turn on the bluetooth and play audio the app crashes.

Below is the logs

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: onLoadChildren must call detach() or sendResult() before returning for package=com.android.bluetooth id=__ROOT__
   at android.service.media.MediaBrowserService.performLoadChildren(MediaBrowserService.java:669)
   at android.service.media.MediaBrowserService.addSubscription(MediaBrowserService.java:600)
   at android.service.media.MediaBrowserService.-wrap3(MediaBrowserService.java)
   at android.service.media.MediaBrowserService$ServiceBinder$3.run(MediaBrowserService.java:272)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

How to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**onLoadChildren()**

> Called to get information about the children of a media item.
>
> Implementations **must call result.sendResult** with the list of children.
>   If loading the children will be an expensive operation that should be
>   performed on another thread, **result.detach** may be called before
>   returning from this function, and then result.sendResult called when
>   the loading is complete.
>
> **In case the media item does not have any children, call
>   MediaBrowserService.Result.sendResult(T) with an empty list.**

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/media/MediaBrowserService.html#onLoadChildren(java.lang.String,%20android.service.media.MediaBrowserService.Result%3Cjava.util.List%3Candroid.media.browse.MediaBrowser.MediaItem%3E%3E,%20android.os.Bundle)

One way or another `result.sendResult()` must be called in the `onLoadChildren()` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like MediaBrowserService is handling it on a wrong state, check the lifecycle here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-a-mediabrowserservice#service-lifecycle